# Regex substitution for substring from position n to m and remove leading 0

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
020075307354H         021133360876      981497910079937800ABC              CDE              FGH                THY                0M19780403015001O+2¹qujzh_¢o\piVN¤«²µerNA¥\^?©E|=V_®¢Zu<£;Æ^TV½IÌc¤±·Gl.ÁEÊO·9y¹Bs¾Ë©ºFT¥*ÉAÂ¬=iÚÒ®{æ*»¨;ÄNÕ®Ûòæ¦'Ñ…9>ÙYKè¹t/R{(>ÔÕBã2½7q¹|u…nztf~¦spw_ZX£\¦~Qa²mn¡¨QX«W±¯¯¦¨d£¾}·`B¶M}Qc|AµOÇ~Äd¤·¯HÇaI_¶²ÂÆYC?xÄR²>½HpÃjÁNLifm@ÕEí¾)ZvÇÊzØ)D&¦áÑM¡ç…1F¥Åh9R[9Fä¤Ãå<÷¼T}Ã…©ÎCDNs«E`É?¤eñ/ï´¯Åíÿt
```

and I want to use 1 Regex substitution to do the following 2 tasks:

1. Get the substring from position 49 to 58 -> 0079937800
2. Strip leading zeros from this substring -> 79937800

The desired end result is `79937800`.

I figured out, that I can substitute the substring of task 1 with `.{48}(.{10}).+`.

The second task of removing leading I figured I can get using `(\b0*([1-9][0-9]*|0)\b)` , but how can I combine both tasks and get a working substitution string?

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?  If so, then which one?

Comment: Just want to use a regex substitution indifferent of programming language like
https://regex101.com/

Comment: The thing is, I wouldn't be looking for a pure regex solution here.

Comment: I understand that this can be solved using 2 different steps with any programming language. My constraint is that I have to solve it in 1 pure Regex solution.

Comment: Fair enough +1 to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the "marker" that follows the 10-character string in a capture group in a positive lookahead, then match the desired substring with an arbitrary number of leading zeroes, and follow it with another positive lookahead to ensure that it is followed by the marker captured in the first capture group. The desired substring will then be in the second capture group:

```
^.{48}(?=.{10}(.*))0*(.*?)(?=\1)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Q61KYJ/1

Since you commented that the requirement for a substitution is mandated by your software, you can simply add `.*` at the end of the above regex and substitute the match with the second capture group:

```
^.{48}(?=.{10}(.*))0*(.*?)(?=\1).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/FcRAGB/1

Comment: This looks great: I see that the result is in Group 2, but how do I get it as a Subsitution Variable as in '$2'?

Comment: Why do you need substitution when you can get the desired substring in a match already?

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it no longer requires support for variable-length lookbehind.

Comment: The software I am using, can only work with the substituded string. Is expecting something like $2

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thats awesome! I tested it with various string and found one where it failssomehow

020075307354H         021133360876      981497910079937877RODRIGUEZ              HERNANDEZ              ESTEBAN                ALBERTO                0M19780403015001O+ 2¹qujzh_¢o\piVN¤«²µerNA¥\^?©E|=V_®¢Zu<£;Æ^TV½IÌc¤±·Gl.ÁEÊO·9y¹Bs¾Ë©ºFT¥*ÉAÂ¬=iÚÒ®{æ*»¨;ÄNÕ®Ûòæ¦'Ñ9>ÙYK
è¹t/R{(>ÔÕBã2½7q¹|unztf~¦spw_ZX¢£\¦~Qa²mn¡¨QX«W±¯¯¦¨d£¾}·`B¶M}Qc|AµOÇ~Äd¤·¯H;ÇaI_¶²ÂÆYC?xÄR²>½HpÃjÁNLifm@ÕEí¾)ZvÇÊzØ)D&¦áÑM¡ç1F¥Åh9R[9Fä¤Ãå=<÷¼T}Ã©ÎCDNs«E`É?¤eñ/ï´¯Åíÿt

Comment: If I try to get $2 I receive. 

79937877
±¯¯¦¨d£¾}·

Comment: Please put your test case in regex101 so that it is not skewed by formatting characters for StackOverflow.

Comment: Otherwise I don't see an issue on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/HPCTmX/1

Comment: There is some weird characters involved here.

Comment: Since that test case contains multiple lines, you would have to enable the "single line" option to make `.` match a newline character as well. Also, disable the "multi line" option to make `^` match only the start of the string: https://regex101.com/r/Lg6Z4Y/1

Comment: If your software doesn't support the "single line" option, you can use a character set of two opposite character classes (such as `[\s\S]`) in place of a dot to match any character, including a newline: https://regex101.com/r/ZNtG09/1